# Помогите преобразовать массив с помощью рекурсии

Tags: php

Начальный PHP-массив:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '96',
    'file_name' => 'Важный документ.docx',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Документы',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\Важный документ.docx',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '97',
    'file_name' => 'июнь_2020.docx',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Документы',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\июнь_2020.docx',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '104',
    'file_name' => '111222.pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\Почта',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\Почта\\111222.pdf',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '110',
    'file_name' => '111222sss.pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\Почта',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\Почта\\111222sss.pdf',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '116',
    'file_name' => 'asdasd.pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\УК',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Документы\\УК\\asdasd.pdf',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '128',
    'file_name' => '111222sss.pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'ДК\\Картинки\\УК',
    'region' => 'Для отдыха',
    'directory' => 'ДК\\Картинки\\УК\\111222sss.pdf',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id_file' => '128',
    'file_name' => 'asdasd.pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'АК\\Приказы',
    'region' => 'Для работы',
    'directory' => 'АК\\Приказы\\asdasd.pdf',
  ),
)
```

Нужно обработать рекурсией по имеющемуся пути **[directory]** , чтобы получилось следующее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => АК
            [name] => АК
            [type] => folder
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Для работы
                    [name] => Для работы
                    [type] => folder
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                        [id] => Документы
                        [name] => Документы
                        [type] => folder
                        [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 96
                                    [name] => Важный документ.docx
                                    [type] => file
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 97
                                    [name] => июнь_2020.docx
                                    [type] => file
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (//если файл с расширением, то массив детей пуст
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
)
```

Все до чего дошел, это до обработки одной ссылки на документ:

```
    function isFolder($value){
        //если в строке присутствует расширение, возвращаем true
        //в противном случае - это папка, и возвращаем false
        if (!stripos($value, '.docx')){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
$newArray=array();
    foreach ($myArray as $k=>$values){
        $newValue = explode('\\', $values['directory']);
        $count = count($newValue);
            if ($newArray[0]['name']!=$newValue[0]){ //если [directory] => АК - то все в массив [0] вставлять
                $newArray[]=[ //строим дерево по ссылке которая имеется
                        'id'=>(isFolder($newValue[0]) ? $newValue[0] : $values['id_file']), //если это папка, то id => будет имя этой папки
                        'name'=>$newValue[0], //пишем имя
                        'type'=>isFolder($newValue[0]) ? 'folder' : 'file', //указываем, папка или файл
                        //а видимо уже включать рекурсию, для перечисления всех дочерних файлов/папок
                        //и заодно проверить [region]
                        'children'=>array(
                            //и кстати, если
                            'id'=>$newValue[1],
                            'name'=> $newValue[1],
                            'type'=>isFolder($newValue[1]) ? 'folder' : 'file',
                            'children'=>array(
                                //вывод всех файлов в директории
                                [
                                    'id'=>(isFolder($newValue[2]) ? 'folder' : $values['id_file']), //выводим id файла
                                    'name'=> $newValue[2],
                                    'type'=>isFolder($newValue[2]) ? 'folder' : 'file',
                                    'children'=> []
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id'=>(isFolder($newValue[2]) ? 'folder' : $values['id_file']),
                                    'name'=> $newValue[2],
                                    'type'=>isFolder($newValue[2]) ? 'folder' : 'file',
                                    'children'=> []
                                ]
                            ),
                        ),
                    ];
            }else{ 
                //если [directory] => ДК - то строить уже новый массив [1]
            }
    }
```

Читал другие ответы/примеры/варианты, но как смонтировать тут рекурсию, никак понять не могу. т.к. есть пара подводных камней:

1. Начальный массив всегда должен иметь в начале [0] либо [1]  -> к нему все остальные child (что в принципе логично, т.к. родительская папка всегда имеет имя  **АК** либо **ДК**.
2. обязательно необходимо сделать прослойку вида *АК\**[region]**\Документы\Важный документ.docx* и тут уже **[region]** является родителем всех остальных т.е. *АК\**[region]**\Приказы\asdasd.docx*.
3. **ID** в виде родитель-ребенок тоже сложны (и в реализации в принципе не нуждается), т.к. если получается **type => folder** то **ID** будет являться имя папки. а если уже файл - то **ID** файла.

Может кто-нибудь помочь с обработкой рекурсии? Заранее благодарен.

```
[children] => Array(
   [id] => АК
   [name] => АК
   [type] => folder
   [children] => Array(вложенность неизвестной длинны))
```

Comment: `var_dump` исходных данный в тексте вопроса не добавляет желания попробовать. Используйте `var_export` =)

Comment: 2. сделайте дополнительный проход по массиву, который вклеит этот ваш `[region]` куда нужно. Не нужно этим усложнять основную задачу постройки дерева.

Comment: @vp_arth изменил на *var_export* :) [region] вклеить, тоже додумался только что. Вопрос в самой рекурсии теперь :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекурсивная обработка списка.
Рекурсия запускается с полной копией оригинального списка, из которого отсекается всё лишнее по префиксу.

[Демо на 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IoVaL)

```
$list = array_map(function($item){
    $path = explode('\\', $item['file_directory']);
    array_splice($path, 1, 0, $item['region']);
    return array(
        'id' => $item['id_file'],
        'path' => $path,
        'name' => $item['file_name'],
    );
}, $inputArray);


function buildTree($items, $prefix = []) {
    $res = [];
    $visited = [];
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if (count($item['path']) < count($prefix)) continue;
        if (array_slice($item['path'], 0, count($prefix)) !== $prefix) continue;

        $node = [];
        if (count($item['path']) > count($prefix)) {
            $curPath = $item['path'][count($prefix)];
            $nextPrefix = array_merge($prefix, [$curPath]);
            $strPrefix = implode('\\', $nextPrefix);
            if ($visited[$strPrefix] ?? false) continue; // префикс обработан?
            $node['type'] = 'folder';
            $node['path'] = $strPrefix;
            $node['name'] = $curPath;
            $node['children'] = buildTree($items, $nextPrefix); // запускаем рекурсию
            $visited[$strPrefix] = true; // префикс обработан
        } else {
            $node['type'] = 'file';
            $node['name'] = $item['name'];            
        }
        $res[] = $node;
    }
    return $res;
}

$tree = buildTree($list);
```

Comment: Идеально! Огромная благодарность! Именно то, что нужно! Жаль, что через монитор нельзя пожать вам руку :)

Answer (score 0):

Простое дерево собирается циклом, вот так:

```
$list = array_map(function($item){
    $path = explode('\\', $item['file_directory']);
    array_splice($path, 1, 0, $item['region']); // [region] :)
    return array(
        'id' => $item['id_file'],
        'path' => $path,
        'name' => $item['file_name'],
    );
}, $inputArray);

$tree = [];
foreach ($list as $item) {
    $resPt = &$tree;
    foreach ($item['path'] as $pathPart) {
        if (!array_key_exists($pathPart, $resPt)) {
            $resPt[$pathPart] = [];
        }
        $resPt = &$resPt[$pathPart];
    }
    $resPt['path'] = implode('\\', $item['path']);
    $resPt['files'][] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item['name']);
    unset($resPt);
}
```

Навтыкать children'ов, при желании, не проблема)
Вывернуть цикл в рекурсию, конечно, можно.. Но зачем?

Comment: Ответ имеет право на жизнь :) Но не так как нужно правда:( В вашем примере - ключем массива является  `$resPt['path']` а может быть только одно - `'children'=>array(и тут другой массив со своим children)`